# How to log SQL queries to a log file with CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I have a CakePHP 1.2 application that makes a number of AJAX calls using the AjaxHelper object.  The AjaxHelper makes a call to a controller function which then returns some data back to the page.

I would like to log the SQL queries that are executed by the AJAX controller functions.  Normally, I would just turn the debug level to 2 in config/core.php, however, this breaks my AJAX functionality because it causes the output SQL queries to be appended to the output that is returned to the client side.

To get around this issue, I would like to be able to log any SQL queries performed to a log file.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't you simply turn the query logging functionality of your database on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a nice way of adding this logging functionality at this link:

http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/Log-SQL-queries-td1281970.html

Basically, in your `cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/` directory, you can make a subclass of the dbo that you're using.  For example, if you're using the dbo_mysql.php database driver, then you can make a new class file called `dbo_mysql_with_log.php`.  The file would contain some code along the lines of the following:

```
App::import('Core', array('Model', 'datasource', 'dbosource', 'dbomysql'));

class DboMysqlWithLog extends DboMysql {
    function _execute($sql) {
        $this->log($sql);
        return parent::_execute($sql);
    }
}
```

In a nutshell, this class modifies (i.e. overrides) the `_execute` function of the superclass to log the SQL query before doing whatever logic it normally does.

You can modify your `app/config/database.php` configuration file to use the new driver that you just created.

Comment: Just for the record: Using `App::import` is the right way to go about `require`ing the dbo_mysql file. Threw errors for me while running unit tests, but this fixed it.

Comment: anyone know how to do this for cake 2? There is no dbo folder in cake 2.

Comment: It's giving "Call to undefined method DboMysqlWithLog::connect()" for me. Any idea what's wrong ?

Comment: can you please mention version of cakephp for which this works.

Comment: @Joelio, I found this blog that worked for me for my Cake 2 application - https://ashokg165.wordpress.com/2015/06/23/logging-sql-queries-into-file-in-cakephp-2/

Answer (score 1):

This is a fantastic way to debug things like this, https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit

Comment: +1, because DebugKit is awesome.  But unfortunately some AJAX calls don't work with DebugKit and so logging to a file can still be helpful.  :-)

Comment: debugkit doesnt seem to log sql statements executed in the post of a controller call, only on the rendering controller calls.