# How can I locate where a query is called from in cakePHP?

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I'm looking at the SQL dump and near the top I see a bunch of queries that I can not find in the code. The model I'm loading is a bit complex with many `$hasMany`, `$hasOne`, and `$belongsTo` associations. One of the `$belongsTo` models is associated to the table being called. But the query is looking for a null `id`, so it just seems odd that it is called in the first place.

Is there a clear way I can back-trace a query to find out its origin?

Answer (score 0):

you can extend your datasource to log every SQL queries in your app like in [How to log SQL queries to a log file with CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721052/how-to-log-sql-queries-to-a-log-file-with-cakephp) (although it should be put in the app/model/datasources/dbo/, not cake/lib)