# How to set CakePHP Debug SQLdump limit

Tags: mysql, debugging, cakephp-2.3

i think its a simple question, but i cant find an answer. In CakePHP on Debug mode 2 i can see the SQL statements. Unfortunately its limited to 200. How can i configure this limit? I need to see much more.

Answer (score 2):

**Quick Fix**

The quick and dirty way to do this is to edit a **core** file.

This is never a good idea, but here it goes:

Goto: `[ROOT]/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php`

Find the definition of the field `$_queriesLogMax = 200;`

Keep in mind that changing the core will make it very difficult to upgrade cake later on. So if you do use this, use it as a temporary fix.

**Good solution**

However the proper way to do this is to create a subclass for the `Mysql` class and overwrite the method `logQuery` to log it to a file or in a buffer to be rendered on the page. Then in your database configuration file (database.php) you need to configure the the `datasource` to be your class.

Here is an example of creating your own [MySQL data source with logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721052/how-to-log-sql-queries-to-a-log-file-with-cakephp).