# CakePHP 2.x query log with MySQL (from only one table)

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, logging, cakephp-2.0

I need to make query log from only one table in MySQL database.
I have lot of sites connected to my database, so I can't set query log directly on mysql. 
I have error which occurs on average once a week. A strange coincidence. 
I want to save logs from whole page. 
 
How to set up query log to file on CakePHP 2.x?

Comment: Consider looking at this thread, should apply to cakePHP2
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721052/how-to-log-sql-queries-to-a-log-file-with-cakephp

Comment: I try to use this method.

Comment: I tried method from [THERE](http://volod-0x16.livejournal.com/10923.html). But I get error Datasource class could not be found.

Comment: And I don't have folder dbo and any driver there(because its 2.x). How to do this?